# Random array string getting nil

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I am using the `random` range function to my array string. Also I am using a filter to not repeat to my array string, but sometimes my first random string is nil.

Random range code:

```
func randomNumber(range: Range<Int> = 1...6) -> Int {
    let min = range.startIndex
    let max = range.endIndex
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min
}
```

I'm getting nil from the `firstItem`:

```
var a = cities[randomNumber(0...80)]

if Marmara.contains(a){
    firstItem = a
    print(firstItem) //It's getting nil sometimes.
    var filteredForSecond = Marmara.filter{$0 != firstItem}
    secondItem = filteredForSecond[randomNumber(0...filteredForSecond.count-1)]
    print(secondItem)
    var filteredForThird = Marmara.filter{$0 != secondItem && $0 != firstItem}
    thirdItem = filteredForThird[randomNumber(0...filteredForThird.count-1)]
    print(thirdItem)
    var filteredForFourth = Marmara.filter{$0 != thirdItem && $0 != secondItem && $0 != firstItem}
    print(fourthItem)
    fourthItem = filteredForFourth[randomNumber(0...filteredForFourth.count-1)]
    //sehirler.removeAtIndex(s)

    print("\(firstItem), \(secondItem), \(thirdItem), \(fourthItem)")
}
```

I have an "81" string in the array using this code.  What should I do to fix this nil string problem?

Comment: Perhaps `a` is nil because it picks an entry of the `cities` array that is nil. Try changing your if statement to: `if Marmara.contains(a) && a != nil`, or ensure you've initialized the entire cities array

Comment: I tried your way and getting empty. It's just get empty. It's not saying nil, but just empty. I f it's getting nil, it is not pass condition. But it's pass and getting empty. I don't get the problem :S Can you test the code please?

Comment: Could you post the code where you created the `cities` array? Or the output of `print(cities)`. None of its entires should be nil for your function to work.

Comment: I created var cities:[String] = [//81 cities in here] and result is like that : ", Aksaray, Kırşehir, Nevşehir" It must be 4 item in here but first is empty. And your answer is @BradzTech I print cities array strings and it isn't nil.

Comment: I cleaned the code. added the check you're saying and first I used other nil condition and it worked now. Thanks. I'll write the working code in my post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not put answers or solutions into questions. Create an answer and put the code there if you found the solution; SO will let you select it after a timeout. Don't add "[solved]" to titles. Instead, select the answer that solved the question; This signals the system the question is solved, and also provides additional points to the answerer. Also, please don't abuse **bold** text; It's as bad as yelling.

Answer (score 1):

I would at least make the following change. See if this fixes the problem.

```
var a = cities[randomNumber(0...cities.count-1)]
```

Comment: I solved the problem and this code piece was helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I'm checking if it is nil, taking again random string and it's not getting nil anymore.

Here is the working code:

```
var a = cities[randomNumber(0...cities.count-1)]

while a.isEmpty{
    a = cities[randomNumber(0...cities.count-1)]
}

if Marmara.contains(a) && a != ""{
    firstItem = a
    if firstItem.isEmpty{
        print("nil")
    }
    print(firstItem)
    var filteredForSecond = Marmara.filter{$0 != firstItem}
    secondItem = filteredForSecond[randomNumber(0...filteredForSecond.count-1)]
    print(secondItem)
    var filteredForThird = Marmara.filter{$0 != secondItem && $0 != firstItem}
    thirdItem = filteredForThird[randomNumber(0...filteredForThird.count-1)]
    print(thirdItem)
    var filteredForFourth = Marmara.filter{$0 != thirdItem && $0 != secondItem && $0 != firstItem}
    print(fourthItem)
    fourthItem = filteredForFourth[randomNumber(0...filteredForFourth.count-1)]
    //sehirler.removeAtIndex(s)

    print("\(firstItem), \(secondItem), \(thirdItem), \(fourthItem)")
}
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However, it still might not work, in case an empty entry is picked twice. Try changing `if a.isEmpty` to `while a.isEmpty`, which will continue picking until a non-empty one is found.

Comment: Ok I changed it with your way and edited the post. It works fine now. Thank you so much! :)